# Problem with image tag on upload in tinymce

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

i have a problem when i upload image with copy paste in tinymce editor.

I get something like this:

```
[img]data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA/gAAADsCAYAAADAdA2HAAAgAElEQVR4Ae3dDXBd1X0g8L+xEeBaQEQc8xFsTDPrVGNcOihWa7BTUFrsZAvNtsLehYEJnWHN7jhuGNEs9GOnbdYUrGkhnnZdmrIDNbtgZUugm5XZjUhiL+7IKE1wjBJnSBwb4mIcXMCOjWUb79z3IT1JT7Kk+6R3Zf8049F9995z7v/8zn3P+t977nlTTp48eTLG+PPugQNxfl3dGEsr....
```

but what i want is `<img src ="data:image/png; base64....... />`

Any suggestion how can i achive that?

this is my setup:

```
tinymceFunction() {
    tinymce.init({
        relative_urls: false,
        document_base_url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1],
        skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
        paste_data_images: true,
        menubar: true,
        statusbar: false,
        selector: '#' + this.elementId,
        branding: false,
        plugins: ['link', 'table', 'autoresize', 'code', 'bbcode', "image paste"],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect  | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link',
        autoresize_min_height: 50,
        autoresize_max_height: 300,
        setup: (editor: any) => {
            this.editor = editor;
            editor.on('keyup change', () => {
                const content = editor.getContent();
                this.onEditorContentChange.emit(content);
            });
        },
        images_dataimg_filter: function (img) {
            return img.hasAttribute('internal-blob');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the `bbcode` plugin:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/bbcode/

That plugin will make TinyMCE return bbcode to you as opposed to HTML.  If you want HTML I would remove the `bbcode` plugin.